# clone.html() is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

I'm wondering what this error message means:

```
clone.html() is null
```

The console refers to the line with following code:

```
clone.filter('p').html(clone.html().replace('a','b').replace('x','y'));
```

This is my code-snippet:

```
var clone = $('div p, div ul').clone();
clone.filter('p').html(clone.html().replace('a','b').replace('x','y'));
```

What did I miss?
Shall I check whether clone.html() is null or not? Or is it a dirty solution?
Any idea or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us where `clone` gets assigned some data.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `$('div p')` selects 'p' tags, so `filter('p')` is not needed.

Comment: It's assigned to all divs with the element p. I've been searching for some p-elements without a div around, but every p-element was wrapped by a div-element. But it's the only way causing this message, isn't it?

Comment: If you're grabbing `<div><p></p></div>` (an empty paragraph) `.html()` will be empty (it only displays child elements/content)

Comment: @Rocket -  I edited the post above. I'm selecting multiple tags.

Comment: @flighter: `filter('p')` is useless here. `$('div p, div ul').filter('p')` is the same as `$('div p')`.

Comment: @rocket - you're right. Thank you. I had to do it for some reason before. Perhaps a coding error. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clone.html()` will be null, if your selector doesn't find anything.  This is because, when jQuery finds nothing, it returns a blank array.  Also, calling `html()` on a set, will only get you the `html` value of the first item.  You should probably be doing this in a loop.

```
var clone = $('div p, div ul').clone();
clone.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html() != ''){
       $this.html($this.html().replace('a','b').replace('x','y'));
    }
});
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I had to remove the '$' sign, but it works. I'll mark it as answered asap.

Comment: @flighter: Remove what '$' sign?  What are you talking about?

Comment: var $this = $(this);
I had to replace $this through another variablename.

Comment: @flighter: Why?  JavaScript variables can have '$' in them.

Answer (score 3):

`clone.html() is null` means that your selector `$('div p')` does not find anything